# How to render each item from array with a delay using CSSTransition?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have an array of items and when the items appear on the DOM I want to render each item with a delay. For now, all the items are rendered simultaneously. Here's my code:

```
  <TransitionGroup className="portfolioItems" component={Container}>
    {portfolio &&
      portfolioItems.map(({ id, url }) => (
        <CSSTransition classNames="portfolioItems" timeout={5000} key={id}>
          <Segment rised style={{ padding: 0, margin: 25 }}>
            <Image src={url} rounded />
          </Segment>
        </CSSTransition>
      ))}
  </TransitionGroup>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Here's my current css:

```
.portfolioItems-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%) scale(0.7, 0.7);
}
.portfolioItems-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%) scale(1, 1);
  transition: 3s all ease-in-out
}
```